# How to add invisible tags to google search

Tags: google-search

I have drop down menu and google search box next to it embedded on my web page. And I want to do such thing:
when user searches something on this google search, selected keyword from drop down menu should applied automatically

this is the code I have right now

```
<FORM method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">

<input type=hidden name=ie value=UTF-8>
<input type=hidden name=oe value=UTF-8>
<TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr><td>
<select name = "type">
    <option value=""> Choose type </option>
    <option value="bitmap">Bitmap</option>
    <option value="vector">Vector</option> 
</select>
<INPUT TYPE=text name=q size=25 maxlength=255 value="">
 <INPUT type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Search">
 </td></tr></TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript. I'd recommend learning about Javascript and using a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to simplify Javascript coding.

In this particular case, you'd need to capture the form's [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event and alter the value of the **q** input field and then let the event go through.

Answer (score 0):

The following (using jQuery) should work. If the user submits the form, the value from the select box is appended to the query before sending off the request to google.

```
$('form').submit(function(){

    var $form = $(this);
    var $q = $form.find('input[name=q]');

    var value_of_select = $form.find('select').val();
    var value_of_q = $q.val();

    $q.val( value_of_q + ' ' + value_of_select);
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/msms5/2/

Comment: I'm complete noob in this field. Can you modify it so I just copy/past it? Thanks a lot

Comment: and where to copy it, after form, before form, in form or where

Comment: Sorry, this is too much. If you have never even used javascript before, you should do some more research yourself first.